# showing validation summary using jquery custom validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form in asp.net MVC 4 razor view like this:

```
  @{Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "register" }))
  {
       <p>@Html.ValidationSummary(false)</p>
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       // different controls here

      <button id="btnRegister" class="btn btn-red-splash s3 hidden" onclick="return GetData();" type="submit">REGISTER</button>
  }
```

I am doing custom validation for a dropdown on button click

```
 function GetData() {
     var IsFormValid = $('form[id=register]').valid();
        return Validate() && IsFormValid;
    }
```

and validation routine is here:

```
 function Validate() {

        var value = $('#ddlAreaID').val();
        var container = $('form#register').find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]");
        if (container == null) {
            $("form#register").append("<div class='validation-summary-errors'><ul>  </ul></div>");
        }

        if (value != "0") {
            if ($('.validation-summary-errors ul li').hasClass('area'))
                $('.validation-summary-errors ul li[class=area]').remove();
            $('#ddlAreaID').addClass('valid').removeClass('input-validation-error');

            return true;
        } else if (value == "0") {

            if (!$('.validation-summary-errors ul li').hasClass('area'))
                $('.validation-summary-errors ul').append('<li class="area">Area must be selected</li>');

            $('#ddlAreaID').addClass('input-validation-error').removeClass('valid');
            return false;
        }
}
```

I am creating validation summary tag ( if all controls are valid then validation summary will not appear and i need to create it) if it is not there and adding li element inside ul. but when area dropdown is not selected, it returns false but validaion summary is not shown ( if all other controls have required value).

here is generated markup:

```
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
```

Please suggest how to fix it

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the built-in unobtrusive validation?

Comment: I have used a custom control which has dropdown and i can not use built in validation in it

Comment: A custom control shouldn't prevent you from using unobtrusive validation. Obviously I don't know what this custom control is, but  surely you're still just validating a form field? I'm just trying to save you from reinventing the wheel!